# C# dictionary where clause fail

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary of key-value pairs. How can I check for `where` clause failure?

```
SomeDictionary.Where(x => x.Value && someOtherBool).First();
```

Is there a way to check if this returned some result without surrounding with `try-catch` block? Sure, I can call `FirstOrDefault()` but I don't get what I need then...

There should really be a method `FirstOrReturn(arg)`...

Comment: I need a way to handle the situation where the "where clause" fails. So now, if nothing is found, I get exception thrown. If I use FirstOrDefault() I get 0 which is not what I want

Comment: Maybe you need not ```Where```, but ```Any``` ?

Comment: Define "fail" do you mean "returns no items" or "throws an exception"?

Comment: When it returns no items, exception is thrown. I need a way to do something like if(!empty(Dict.where()))...so check if it returned items or not

Answer (score 7):

`FirstOrReturn(arg)` should be

```
.Where(x => x.Value && someOtherBool).DefaultIfEmpty(arg).First();
```

Comment: which is faster this implementation or using Any? like the other answer

Comment: @MidTwo I'd say if you use `Any` you have to determine the result in another iteration/request - so this one should be faster

Comment: @fubo ok +1 for that just curious though